# Resize ImageView's height to match original image's aspect ratio using Glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I have an `ImageView` in `GridLayout` that is showing an image loaded from Url. GridLayout has 2 columns and it is all stretched to the entire screen. I need an entire image to be visible without any changes to the aspect ratio. Since the screen width can vary on many devices, I need the height to be calculated from the width of `ImageView` (which needs to fill the GridLayout) and from the aspect ratio of the downloaded image.

My idea was to set the **width** of `ImageView` to `match_parent` and **height** to `wrap_content` and then tell *Glide* that I wanna the height to be calculated to fit the aspect ratio of the image, but I am struggling to do that.

So far I have this in the layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

And this in adapter:

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                    .load(item.getImageUrl())
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().error(R.color.black_one))
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this [article](https://medium.com/@sasanksunkavalli/android-constraintlayout-layout-constraintdimensionratio-33bd2293f34c). Using a **`ConstraintLayout`** there is an option to use **`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio`** parameter. You need to set one of the dimensions to **`0dp`** and then you just choose whatever ratio you want and that is it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/top_image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive what you are looking for is to load images like instagram feed does, dynamic height with fixed width, without cropping the content. Then set the height to wrap content, width to match parent and **set adjustViewBounds to true.**

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

The android:adjustViewBounds parameter does the magic of setting the imageview height dynamically.